# MongoDB Shard key - enforce in every query

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

If we use a compound shard key say {a,b} is there a possibility to throw error on any query which do not include these fields in the query at the java driver level. i.e any callbacks/life cycle event before query gets executed...like AbstractMongoEventListener - here we have options of onAfterLoad and  onAfterConvert but our requirement is before executing the query... Something at the java driver level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand why you want this capability(If the query does not include even a single sharded key as part of its criteria then it will result in "scatter and gather" kind of queries which result in significant performance degradation). But the best practice for APIs suggest that a API should be designed for a single purpose and be generic ,if we tend to add this capability to the Java driver then it will tend it impose a additional constraint which might not be required.Hence there is no out of the box API that does this for you.

```
What you can do to make it work - Write a wrapper on top of this API with the additional capability.
```

Comment: Thanks @vmr for quick response. Exactly the reason we needed the enforcing :) Will look into the possibility of wrapper and get back

Comment: For anyone looking for something similar here is what i did-
1) Create a custom MongoTemplate class extending MongoTemplate
2) Override 'find(Query query, Class<T> entityClass, String collectionName)' and  'findOne(Query query, Class<T> entityClass, String collectionName)' and do any validation/manipulation there
3) In config extending AbstractMongoConfiguration override 'mongotemplate' method and return an object of the custom Mongotemplate that you created